# Test of equality (equals and hash code method)

Tags: java

As per the below link

[Hashcode and equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990734/hashcode-and-equals)

**So it is assumed that if 2 objects are equal (that is, equals() returns true), then their hashCodes() must return the same value.**

But consider the below example

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Demo d1 = new Demo(123);
        Demo d2 = new Demo(123);

        System.out.println("d1.hashCode()-->" + d1.hashCode());
        System.out.println("d2.hashCode()-->" + d2.hashCode());
        System.out.println(d1.equals(d2));
    }
}

class Demo {

    private int name;

    Demo(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Double d = Math.random() * 1000;
        return d.intValue();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ((o instanceof Demo) && (((Demo) o).getName() == this.getName())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

the output of the above program is

> d1.hashCode()-->85
>
> d2.hashCode()-->692
>
> true

Here the question is even though the hash code is different the equals method return true.
So does it mean for equality of object we do not need same hash code

Answer (score 4):

Some implementations (for instance `HashMap`) depend on the fact that when two instances are equal their hashcode should be the same.  However, purely using equals will not check hashcodes for those instances.

In the case of a hashmap, elemets are first divided into different hash buckets based on the hashcodes of objects (for performance reasons).  Inside a bucket, equals is used to check object equality.  If two equal instances don't have the same `hashCode` they will end up in different buckets and that *might* result in unexpected behaviour due to the contract violation.

Answer (score 3):

It is bad implementation of `hashCode()` , You should follow that contract.

`equals` has nothing to do with `hashcode` independently.

But when you use hashing data structure you <strike>should</strike> must follow this thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* implement `hashCode` using random numbers! It should *always* be computed using the same fields as `equals` uses. Otherwise, your objects will be unusable as keys in `HashMap`, `HashSet`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idea is that when you implemente the `equals` method you should implement the `hashCode` method, and if `a.equals(b)` then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`. Although there isn't anything in the Java compiler or Runtime that enforces this.

Answer (score 0):

In Hashcode it is always required that if two objects are equal then their hashCode always have to be the same other wise the hash collections(HashMap, HashSet etc. wont work correctly)

Well in your case one of the implementations of can be -

```
public int hashCode() {
    return this.getName();
}
```

OR if you want to mix it up a bit -

```
public int hashCode() {
    return String.valueOf(this.getName()).hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Actually my question is for equality of object we need same hash code or not?

Comment: Yes we do. Read the first sentence of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

First imp thing you should not use random number to implement the `hashcode()` method.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashcode();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o !=null && o instanceOf Demo)
    {
        Demo d=(Demo) o;
        if(this.d.name==d.name)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```