# Does Hashcode equality imply refer reference based equality?

Tags: java, object, methods, overriding

I read that to use **equals()** method in java we also have to override the hashcode() method and that the equal (logically) objects should have eual hashcodes, but doesn't that imply reference based equality! Here is my code for overridden equals() method, how should I override hashcode method for this:

```
@Override    
public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if (!(o instanceof dummy))
                return false;
            dummy p = (dummy) o;
            return (p.getName() == this.getName() && p.getId() == this.getId() && p.getPassword() == this.getPassword());

        }
```

I just trying to learn how it works, so there are only three fields, namely *name* , *id* and *password* , and just trying to compare two objects that I define in the main() thats all! I also need to know if it is **always necessary** to override hashcode() method along with equals() method?

Comment: Remember 'return 1;' is a completely legal implementation of 'hashcode();'  that usually summarizes what you can and can't trust it for :)

Comment: Careful!  Your sections p.getName() == this.getName() and p.getPassword() == this.getPassword() are not correct (assuming they are strings or non-primitives).  You should be using p.getName().equals(this.getName()) and p.getPassword().equals(this.getPassword()).  You should also add null checks for accessing those two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though failure to override `hashCode()` will only break usage of your class in `HashSet`, `HashMap`, and other hashCode dependent structures, you should still override `hashCode()` to maintain the contract described by `Object`.

The general strategy of most `hashCode()` implementations is to combine the hash codes of the fields used to determine equality. In your case, a reasonable `hashCode()` may look something like this:

```
public int hashCode(){
    return this.getName().hashCode() ^ this.getId() ^ this.getPassword().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Hashcode equality does not imply **anything**. However, hashcode *inequality* should imply that `equals` will yield false, and any two items that are equal should always have the same hashcode.

For this reason, it is always wise to override hashcode with equals, because a number of data structures rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you aren't actually comparing your fields' values.  Use `equals()` instead of `==` to make your implementation of equal correct.

```
return (p.getName().equals(this.getName()) && ...
```

(Note that the above code can cause null reference exceptions if `getName()` returns null: you may want to use a utility class as described [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17))

And yes `hashCode()` would be called when you use some hashing data structure like HashMap,HashSet

> You must override hashCode() in every
>   class that overrides equals(). Failure
>   to do so will result in a violation of
>   the general contract for
>   Object.hashCode(), which will prevent
>   your class from functioning properly
>   in conjunction with all hash-based
>   collections, including HashMap,
>   HashSet, and Hashtable.
>
> from *Effective Java*, by Joshua Bloch

**Also See**

- [overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [hashcode-and-equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990734/hashcode-and-equals)
- [Nice article on `equals()` & `hashCode()`](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html)

Comment: "In your code, you aren't actually comparing your fields' values. Use equals() instead of == to make your implementation of equal correct." - If the types of the fields being compared are primitive or immutable (such as String) then `==` will work perfectly fine, and it won't fail if the getters are null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `hashCode()` when you *override* `equals()`. Merely using `equals()` is not enough to require you to override `hashCode()`.

Answer (score -1):

The idea with `hashCode()` is that it is a unique representation of your object in a given space. Data structures that hold objects use hash codes to determine where to place objects. In Java, a `HashSet` for example uses the hash code of an object to determine which *bucket* that objects lies in, and then for all objects in that bucket, it uses `equals()` to determine whether it is a match.

If you don't override `hashCode()`, but do override `equals()`, then you will get to a point where you consider 2 objects to be **equal**, but Java collections don't see it the same way. This will lead to a lot of strange behaviour.

Comment: -1 HashSet does not use hash code to determine if an object is already part of the set. It only uses it to determine where to look.

Comment: Techinically, you're right, hash to determine the bucket and then checks equal to determine if it is in there... I'll clarify

Comment: 'it is a unique representation of your object'. No. There is no uniqueness requirement.

Comment: Not only is there no uniqueness requirement, but it'd be impossible to have unique 32-bit hash codes for, say, every (128-bit) GUID.  Aside from that, there is an expectation that if`a.equals(b)`, then a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()`, meaning there are times when two objects are *expected* to have equal hash codes.