# Java HashMap with Int Array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am using this code to check that array is present in the `HashMap`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        HashMap<int[], String> map = new HashMap<int[], String>();
        map.put(new int[]{1, 2}, "sun");
        System.out.println(map.containsKey((new int[]{1, 2})));
    }
}
```

But this prints `False`. How can I check that array is present in the `HashMap`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is because the two `int[]` aren't equal.

```
System.out.println(
    (new int[] { 1, 2 }).equals(new int[] { 1, 2 })
); // prints "false"
```

`Map` and other Java Collections Framework classes defines its interface in terms of `equals`. From [`Map API`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the `equals` method. For example, the specification for the `containsKey(Object key)` method says: "returns `true` if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key `k` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`."

Note that they don't have to be the same object; they just have to be `equals`. Arrays in Java extends from `Object`, whose default implementation of `equals` returns true only on object identity; hence why it prints `false` in above snippet.

---

You can solve your problem in one of many ways:

- Define your own wrapper class for arrays whose `equals` uses [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) `equals/deepEquals` method.

  - And don't forget that when you `@Override equals(Object)`, you must also `@Override hashCode`
- Use something like `List<Integer>` that *does* define `equals` in terms of the values they contain
- Or, if you *can* work with reference equality for `equals`, you *can* just stick with what you have. Just as you shouldn't expect the above snippet to ever print `true`, you shouldn't ever expect to be able to find your arrays by its values alone; you must hang-on to and use the original references every time.

---

#### See also:

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [How to ensure hashCode() is consistent with equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410236/how-to-ensure-hashcode-is-consistent-with-equals)
- [Understanding the workings of equals and hashCode in a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap)

#### API

- [`Object.equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Object.hashCode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

  - It's essential for a Java programmer to be aware of these contracts and how to make them work with/for the rest of the system

Answer (score 8):

You are comparing two different references.
Something like this will work:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
     HashMap<int[],String> map= new HashMap<int[],String>();
     int[] a = new int[]{1,2};
     map.put(a, "sun");
     System.out.println(map.containsKey(a));
    }
}
```

Since `a` is the same reference, you will receive `true` as expected. If your application has no option of passing references to do the comparison, I would make a new object type which contains the `int[]` and override the `equals()` method (don't forget to override `hashCode()` at the same time), so that will reflect in the `containsKey()` call.

Comment: Implementing only `equals()` is **not** enough, you need to implement `hashCode()` as well. See Chapter 3 of Effective Java (available online: http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a different approach. As mentioned before, the problem is with arrays equality, which is based on reference equality and makes your map useless for your needs. 
Another potential problem, assuming that you use ArrayList instead, is the problem of consistency: if you change a list after is has been added to the map, you will have a hashmap corruption since the position of the list will not reflect its hashcode anymore.

In order to solve these two problems, I would use some kind of immutable list. You may want to make an immutable wrapper on int array for example, and implement equals() and hashCode() yourself.

Comment: This is explained here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your array is doing an '==' comparison, i.e. it's checking the reference. When you do containsKey(new int[] { ... }), it's creating a new object and thus the reference is not the same.

If you change the array type to something like `ArrayList<Integer>` that should work, however I would tend to avoid using Lists as map keys as this is not going to be very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The `hashCode()` implementation for arrays is derived from `Object.hashCode()`, so it depends on the memory location of the array. Since the two arrays are instantiated separately, they have different memory locations and thus different hashcodes. If you made one array it would work:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2};
map.put(arr, "sun");
System.out.println(map.containsKey(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got two different objects that happen to contain the same values, because you've called new twice.

One approach you might use is to create a "holder" class of your own, and define that class's equals and hash methods.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to map `Strings` to arrays instead of the other way around?

Anyway, to answer your question, the problem is you are creating a `new` array when you call `containsKey()`.  This returns false between you you have two separately `new`ed arrays that happen to have the same elements and dimension.  See Yuval's answer to see the correct way of checking if an array is contained as a key.

An alternative, more advanced, approach is to create your own class that wraps an array and overwrites `hashCode()` so that two arrays with the same dimension and elements will have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

The two instances of int[] are different and not equal.

A nice approach would be to convert the int array to String using Arrays.toString(arr):

```
HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<>();
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2};
h.put(Arrays.toString(a), "sun");
h.get(Arrays.toString(new int[]{1, 2})); // returns sun
```

Comment: new int[]{12} will also return the sun which would be false . So, instead of just converting it to string we can put some kind of identifier like #
So,
 int[]{1,2} will be #1#2 AND int[]{12} will be #12