# Java ArrayList: contains() method returns false when arraylist contains the given object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains, evaluation

I have a problem with the `contains()` method which returns false even though the `ArrayList` contains the given `Object`.
My code is following:

```
String [] transaction = dbConnection.getPendingTransaction(username);
if (!onlineConnection.getSentTransactionRequests().contains(transaction)) {
    onlineConnection.getSentTransactionRequests().add(transaction);

    String packet = "RTR" + "_" + transaction[0] + "_" + transaction[2] + 
                        "_" + transaction[3] + "_" + transaction[4];
    onlineConnection.send(packet);
}
```

I have tried `Thread.sleep()` between iterations, so the `ArrayList` wasn't load as eagerly without success.

Comment: `equals` and `hashcode` are apparently not your friends.

Comment: Please, please, please model your transaction as a proper object, and not as an array of strings. Then see @haylem's comment above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `hashCode()` and `equals()` of arrays are a bit broken when it comes to this (it is a long different discussion why).

A possible work around is to use `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` instead of `ArrayList<String[]>`, the `equals()` method for `ArrayList` will be as you expect it to.

For example:

```
    ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add("asdf");
    l2.add("asdf");
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> coll = new ArrayList<>();
    coll.add(l1);
    System.out.println(coll.contains(l2));
```

Will yield `true`, as expected

Comment: If this is indeed the issue, the "long different discussion why" would be worth it.

Comment: @DonRoby: I believe the main reason it is still this way in java 7 is backward compability, to be honest. I believe that if the designers could change it without change the backward compability guideline of java - they would... But I am not an architect in Oracle, so I could be wrong. I also believe it is off topic.

Comment: This is indeed the issue, and the reason is in the related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

Look at getPendingTransaction and getSentTransactionRequests if it should return SAME array and not create NEW one. Second, try to debug and look for arrays object id. If this is not same, but it should be (and contains same elements), try to workaround of this (for instance create comparator or List or something like).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `equals` for arrays is defined to be reference equality.  In other words, two different arrays that contain the same elements are NOT equal ... according to the `equals` method.

If you want `equals` for the "transaction" objects to be based on the equality of the strings, you need to create a custom class to hold the `String[]`, and override the `equals` method and the `hashcode` method.

---

By the way, array `equals(Object)` method is not "a bit broken".  The defined semantics of `equals` are simply reflecting the fact that any array object is inherently mutable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `String [] transaction` is object. And when you are calling `contains` list compares new object to some other one using `equals` method. Imagine it like doing

```
new Object().equals(new Object())
```

Comment: Not entirely correct, note that if the collection contains "asdf" and you check for `list.contains(new String("asdf"))` you will get true.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `List<String[]>`, possibly you are out of luck of using `equals()` or `hashCode()` it seems......

Maybe you'd better create method to do compare your objects

Something like

```
public static boolean stringArrayListEquals(List<String[]> list, List<String[]> list2) {
    if (list.size() != list2.size()) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i){
        if (!Arrays.equals(list.get(i), list2.get(i)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

To test for `contains()`, you would need another loop...

Though you should seriously use `List<List<String>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the similar issue. I just wrote the below snippet:

```
assertContains(list, toLookFor);  // To call the below private method  

private void assertContains(ArrayList<String> list, String toLookFor) {
        String arrayListToString = rulesList.toString();
        
         if (arrayListToString.contains(toLookFor))
                System.out.println("The list contains "+ toLookFor);
            else
                System.out.println("The list does not contains "+ toLookFor);
        
    }
```