# Java remove duplicates from List<List<float[]>>

Tags: java, list

I am attempting to remove duplicate records found in a `List<List<float[]>>`. I attempted to use a collection which does not allow duplicates(HashList) but I was unable to figure out how to cast this properly. To loop through all of my elements I would perform.

```
List<List<float[]>> tmp; 

for(int i=0; i<tmp.get(0).size();i++){
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(tmp.get(0).get(i)));
}
```

I want to remove them from the list inside. So all elements found at tmp.get(0).get(Here to remove)

```
tmp.get(0).get(1) =[-70.89,42.12]

tmp.get(0).get(2) =[-70.89,42.12]
```

I would like to remove  tmp.get(0).get(2)

Current implementation, which works when there is only 1 duplicate but not multiple duplicates.

```
for(int i=0; i<old.get(0).size();i++){
            if(i == old.get(0).size()-1){
                System.out.println("max size");
                return old;
            }
            else if(Arrays.toString(old.get(0).get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(Arrays.toString(old.get(0).get(i+1)))){
                old.get(0).remove(i);
                i++;
            } else {
            i++;
            }
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates from the whole list or from the lists contained inside?

Comment: You want to remove duplicate `List<float[]>`s?

Comment: Related: [equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Comment: Sorry, I want to remove them from the list inside. So all elements found at tmp.get(0).get(Here to remove)

Comment: You mention `ArrayList` in the tags.  Are you aware of the method [`ArrayList.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: if you are removing individual elements from the internal arrays, should be arrays be resized (new arrays created)?

Comment: How about you provide some example input and output to make it clear what this should do.

Comment: So, if there exists two ARRAYS that have the same elements one of the ARRAYS should be removed. However, if two arrays share a single common value the value should not be removed? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
List<List<Float[]>> outterList;
Set<Float[]> mySet = new HashSet<Float[]>();
for (List<Float[]> innerList : outterList){
    Iterator<Float[]> iterator = innerList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Float[] array = iterator.next();
        boolean added = mySet.add(array);
        if (!added)
           iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

To make the comparison, try converting to `BigDecimal` via [new BigDecimal(double, MathContext)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28int,%20java.math.MathContext%29)

Update:
The test fails. seems to be an issue with comparing Arrays in a HashSet.

```
@Test
public void testArrays() {
    Set<String[]> set = new HashSet<String[]>();
    set.add(new String[] { "12.3f", "33.4f" });
    Assert.assertFalse(set.add(new String[] { "12.3f", "33.4f" }));
}
```

**Update**

So arrays work differently. Here you go:

This uses Guava's [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and [Iterables.any()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29). This solution is less efficient than using a `Set` since it has to iterate the `List` each time but it does work if performance is not an issue.

```
private static <T> Predicate<T[]> equals(final T[] array) {
    return new Predicate<T[]>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(T[] arg0) {
            return Arrays.equals(array, arg0);
        }
    };
}

public static <T> List<List<T[]>> ProcessList(List<List<T[]>> old) {
    List<T[]> mySet = new ArrayList<T[]>();
    for (List<T[]> innerList : old) {
        Iterator<T[]> iterator = innerList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T[] array = iterator.next();
            Predicate<T[]> contains = equals(array);

            if (Iterables.any(mySet, contains)) {
                iterator.remove();
            } else {
                mySet.add(array);
            }
        }
    }
    // for (int i = 0; i < old.get(0).size(); i++) {
    // System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(old.get(0).get(i)));
    // }
    return old;
}
```

This test:

```
@Test
public void testListsFloat() {
    List<List<Float[]>> outter = new ArrayList();

    List<Float[]> inner1 = new ArrayList();
    inner1.add(new Float[] { 12.3f, 33.4f });
    inner1.add(new Float[] { 12.2f, 33.2f });
    inner1.add(new Float[] { 12.3f, 33.4f });

    List<Float[]> inner2 = new ArrayList();
    inner2.add(new Float[] { 12.1f, 33.1f });
    inner2.add(new Float[] { 12.2f, 33.2f });
    inner2.add(new Float[] { 12.3f, 33.4f });

    outter.add(inner1);
    outter.add(inner2);

    outter = ProcessList(outter);
    for (List<Float[]> list : outter) {
        for (Float[] array : list) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
}
```

resulted in this output:

[12.3, 33.4]
[12.2, 33.2]
[12.1, 33.1]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I return a List<List<float[]> from that? Tried outterList.set(0, (List<float[]>) mySet);
    but that doesnt seem to be correct implementation

Comment: return outterList. It has now been modified via the `remove` calls to the iterators.

Comment: hm, that seems to still contain duplicates . 

 public static List<List<float[]>>  ProcessList( List<List<float[]>> old){ 
  Set<float[]> mySet = new HashSet<float[]>();
  for (List<float[]> innerList : old){
      Iterator<float[]> iterator = innerList.iterator();
      while(iterator.hasNext()){
          float[] array = iterator.next();
          boolean added = mySet.add(array);
          if (!added)
             iterator.remove();
      }
  } 
  
  for(int i=0; i<old.get(0).size();i++){
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(old.get(0).get(i)));
  }
     
  return old; 
 }

Comment: Please provide the output that suggests it didn't work? What is your definition of duplicates? This will only remove duplicate arrays (two arrays with the exact same elements in the same order).

Comment: Ohhhh, you may also be running into issues with comparing Float values. Floats are not exact so that might be part of the issue. Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe my array should be a String instead of float. duplicate values are as follows ; "[-72.27, 42.05]
[-72.27, 42.05]
[-72.27, 42.05]
[-72.27, 42.05]
[-72.27, 42.05]
[-72.26, 42.05]
[-72.26, 42.05]"

Comment: Yeah, I think your issue might be that `Float` comparison is always sketchy because they could differ at the 105th decimal. I suggest converting to `String` with a set precision or `BigDecimal`. Then comparison should work better.

Comment: Yeah I tried string, however it yielded the same result. There are still duplicates

Comment: Then we are missing something or not understanding each other because this should work. Can you provide a unit test that executes the method and demonstrates the behavior?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37675/discussion-between-user2524908-and-john-b)

Comment: Sorry, chat is blocked from my work. However, I have posted the solution that should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That solution will certainly work because this is a one time script to remove duplicates from these millions of jsons I have. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for `Set<List<float[]>>`.

Comment: Ive updated the question with some additional implementation.

Comment: Yeah I gave that a try, I didnt even think to use a set. I am still getting duplicates however:(. So what my code is doing is reading from CSV which has a JSON column. I am using GSON to parse the JSON into a   public Set<List<float[]>> coordinates = new HashSet<>();.  When I output them using List<float[]> tmp = p.coordinates.iterator().next();
   for(int i=0; i<tmp.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp.get(i)));
   
   }      There are still duplicates

Comment: The problem is that array's equals is the same with arr1 == arr2. However, you have 2 different references with same values. My guess : extend ArrayList and override the equals(you will also need hashcode overrided too, because you will use HashSet) method to use Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2). So, you will have Set<List<float[]>> set = new HashSet<MyArrayList<float[]>>(); . Smart IDEs will generate hashcodes for you.

Comment: Im sorry but I am not that experienced with java. What is MyArrayList referencing? Is it my variable List<List<float[]>> tmp; ?

Comment: MyArrayList is your custom ArrayList(MyArrayList extends ArrayList). You must override the equals method to use Arrays.equals when you need to check if 2 arrays have the same values. Also, because you are using HashSet, you need to override the hashcode. I can do it for you, but a little bit later.

Comment: -1 for extending `ArrayList`, which is essentially always a bad idea, but instead you should almost certainly be creating a custom class to wrap a `float[]`.

Comment: I can't see why is a bad idea, can you explain? I am here to learn as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to have no duplicates while filling. Though it's an implementation of `Set`, you can wrap it into a `List` if you need `List` methods.