# Find a base case for a recursive void method

Tags: java, methods, recursion

I am doing homework.  I would like to build a base case for a recursion where ordering given numbers (list2) in ascending order.  Purpose of writing this codes is that when all numbers are in ascending order then should stop calling a method called ascending(list2, list1); and all values in list2 should be shipped to list1.  For instance, list2 = 6,5,4,3,2,1 then list2 becomes empty and list1 should be 1,2,3,4,5,6.  I am trying to compare result with previous one and if matches then stop.  But I can't find the base case to stop it.  In addition, Both ascending() and fixedPoint() are void method.  Anybody has idea? lol Took me 3 days...

When I run my code then

6,5,4,3,2,1

5,6,4,3,2,1

4,5,6,3,2,1

3,4,5,6,2,1

2,3,4,5,6,1

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

1,2,3,4,5,6

infinite.............

```
public class Flipper
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Flipper aFlipper = new Flipper();

    List<Integer> content = Arrays.asList(6,5,4,3,2,1);
    ArrayList<Integer> l1 =  new ArrayList<Integer>(content);
    ArrayList<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // empty list

    aFlipper.fixedPoint(l2,l1);

    System.out.println("fix   l1 is "+l1);
    System.out.println("fix   l2 is "+l2);
}
public void fixedPoint(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
    // data is in list2
    ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // empty list

    if (temp1.equals(list2)) 
    {
        System.out.println("found!!!");             
    }

    else
    {
        ascending(list2, list1); // data, null
        temp1 = list1; // store processed value
        System.out.println("st list1 is "+list1);
        System.out.println("st list2 is "+list2);
    }
    fixedPoint(list2, list1); // null, processed data       
}
```

Second try after receiving advice.

```
else        {
            temp1 = list2;
            System.out.println("temp1: "+temp1);
```

**// temp1 printed out the value assigned**

```
            // store only previous value
            ascending(list2, list1); // data, null

            temp2 = list1;
            // store previous value

            System.out.println("temp1: "+temp1);
```

**// after invoking ascending() temp1 
becomes empty lol  So not able to compare in if statement....
Can anybody correct it?**

```
            System.out.println("temp2: "+temp2);
        }
        fixedPoint(list2, list1); // previous, proceeded data
```

**After brain storming with dasblinkenlight, Julien S, Nikolas, ZouZou and vels4j a solution found.  I appreciate your contribution of thought! :-)**

```
public void fixedPoint(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                       ArrayList<Integer> list2)
    {
        List<Integer> content = Arrays.asList(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(content); 
        fixedPoint(list2, list1, temp1);
    }
    // Since it is recursive method I needed to create another parameter
    // to store temporary values.
    public void fixedPoint(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                           ArrayList<Integer> list2, 
                           ArrayList<Integer> temp)
    {


        ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        temp1 = temp;

        if (temp1.equals(list2))
        {
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            temp1.clear(); 
            for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) 
            // To store temp value of list2, 
            // I used add method.  Because ArrayList is an object type so if I assign 
            // list2 to temp1 then it will assign memory address rather 
            // than values.  Thus I will lose the values after invoking ascending() as 
            // all elements of list2 will shipped to list1.  So List2 becomes empty.
            {
                temp1.add(list2.get(i));
            }
            ascending(list2, list1);

            fixedPoint(list2, list1, temp1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does `ascending` do? Could you post the code for it?

Comment: Sorry about it.  I can't post directly here cos it is given by a tutor.  As I am not sure it can be shared online.  But I think it is enough explained what ascending method does with an example.  I cannot modify the ascending method with any reason as well :-) Thanks.

Comment: You have no **stop** condition

Comment: Yup it is recursive method so the basecase is the stop condition thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Purpose of writing this codes is that when all numbers are in ascending order then should stop calling a method called `ascending(list2, list1)`

Then you should add a loop that checks for the elements of `list1` to be in ascending order, like this:

```
public void fixedPoint(ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
    boolean isAscending = true;
    for (int i = 1 ; (isAscending) && (i < list2.size()) ; i++) {
        isAscending = list2.get(i-1) < list2.get(i);
    }
    if (isAscending) {
        ... // Insert code to copy the data from list2 to list1.
        ... // Note that a simple assignment is not going to work here!
        System.out.println("found!!!");
        return;
    }
    // It's not in ascending order - continue recursing down.
    ascending(list2, list1);
    ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1); // store processed value
    fixedPoint(list2, list1);
    // temp1 makes the old value of list1 available for comparison
    System.out.println("st list1 is "+list1);
    System.out.println("st list1 was "+temp1);
    System.out.println("st list2 is "+list2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  I noted your codes.  Buy can you think of way to compare previous result and list of numbers will passed in?

Comment: @EvanS Recursive code has no "previous" state, each level of invocation must deal only with its own data passed as parameters. You can definitely compare data before and after calling `fixedPoint` recursively, though - for that you need to make a copy of the list into a `temp` before the call, make the call, and then do the comparison. That has little to do with establishing your base case, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Dude that's  exactly what I am attempting here.  Could you bring your idea into codes?  Cos I am new to recursion.  If I can see best example would be no better than any other explanation in this case.  Thanks.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight Thanks for your update!  It was applied for the codes but ended up with a linefeed and seemed stuck on that stage forever.  But I learned from your codes ((isAscending) && (i < list2.size()) can be used as step statement for a for-loop.  Cool.  I figured out a solution will be pasted soon :-) Thanks for your participation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably arises from the usage of `temp1.equals(list2)`. What you want to use is `Arrays.equals(temp1, list2)`.

An explanation for this is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java) by Peter Lawrey.

**Edit**
Yeah, I should probably read better.

I just checked and it appears ArrayList inherits `.equals()` from `List` which is defined differently than `array.equals()` and "should" work.

Comment: Arrays.equals won't work because temp1 and list2 are ArrayLists and no Array. CollectionsUtils.isEqualCollection works perfectly in this case.

Comment: @Nikolas Thanks for your suggestion.  I noted for use of Arrays next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no return in fixedPoint when the case is found. Therefore the line  fixedPoint(list2, list1);
will be processed regardless of the fixed point. 
I am not able to test since ascending method is not provided, however I think that

```
if (CollectionUtils.isEqualsCollection(list1,list2) 
{
    System.out.println("found!!!"); 
    return;            
}
```

would do the job.

You will require Apache-commons Collections to perform the equality on lists with [isEqualsCollection](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Comment: return may causes the issue. However what is wrong with `temp1.equals(list2)` ?

Comment: You can use equals to compare ArrayList, it has been overridden in `AbstractList.java.`

Comment: @Julien S.   I am getting this messeage...if (CollectionUtils.isEqualsCollection(list1,list2)) 
      ^
  symbol:   variable CollectionUtils
  location: class Flipper
1 error

Comment: @ZouZou I tested equals method with ArrayList yup it worked.  So I applied but do you see any logic issue I should correct?

Comment: @EvanS, did you import the apache commons collection library into your project ?

Comment: @Julien S I have no idea apache commone collection lib...Could you give me a full statement start with import.?

Comment: Import the library from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/ in your project. Your IDE will complete the import.