# Why aren't these two arrays equal?

Tags: java, arrays, equals

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char [] d = {'a','b','c','d'};
    char [] e = {'d','c','b','a'};
    Arrays.sort(d);
    Arrays.sort(e);
    System.out.println(e);           //console : abcd
    System.out.println(d);           //console : abcd
    System.out.println(d.equals(e)); //console : false
}
```

Why are the arrays unequal? I'm probably missing something but it's driving me crazy. Isn't the result supposed to be true? And yes I have imported java.util.Arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Isn't the result supposed to be true?

No. You're calling `equals` on two different array references. Arrays don't override `equals`, therefore you get reference equality. The references aren't equal, therefore it returns false...

To compare the values in the arrays, use [`Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D%29).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(d, e));
```

Comment: I confused it with String's equal method, I feel so dumb. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This has always seemed unhelpful (of java) to me; if people want the `==` they can use `==`, I understand it as a default but I cannot see why it wasn't overridden in this case (or made not available at all as arrays are special)

Answer (score 11):

Arrays do *not* override `Object#equals()`. Use:

```
Arrays.equals(d, e);
```

instead to perform a value-based comparison.

**However:**

`Arrays.equals` does *not* work as expected for multidimensional arrays. It will compare the references of the first level of arrays instead of comparing all levels. Refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java#comment21916282_8777279), or use [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) in the same manner.

Comment: @Quincunx If you encode the URL using `%29` and `%28` for parentheses it should process correctly. Thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: Thanks for the tip (I deleted my comment because you included it in your post; thought you found it elsewhere)