# Code segment on arrays java

Tags: java

So I was doing review, and came across this question that I'm not very sure about.

Consider the following code segment:

```
int[] A = {1,2,3};

int[] B = {1,2,3};

int[] C = A;
```

After this code executes, which of the following expressions would evaluate to true?

```
I.  A.equals (B)

II. A == B

III. A ==C
```

I only

II only

III only

I and III only

I, II, and III

I thought it was I only, but one of my classmates said that it was III only.

Could some please explain this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can easily test it.

Comment: Yes I think your friend is right, see this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Comment: use lower-case names for Java variables please.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the above linked question by @J L:

> Arrays.equals(array1, array2) works as you would expect (i.e. compares
>   content), array1.equals(array2) falls back to Object.equals
>   implementation, which in turn compares identity, and thus better
>   replaced by == (for purists: yes I know about null).

Simply put, you are setting C equal to A, so that's why A == C is true. You performing an `Object.equals` essentially. While it appears on the surface that `A.equals(B)` would be true, they are not because of the internals behind `Object.equals`.

So your friend is right.

Answer (score 1):

The third has a and c pointing the same object. The others not.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is correct.

In the code you are saying C = A.

This means that C is the same exact object as A.

In other cases, they are not the same object, although they have the same content.

You might want to have a look at Arrays.deepEquals which returns true (your code is slightly modified):

package arrays;

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class ArraysTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer[] A = { 1, 2, 3 };
      Integer[] B = { 1, 2, 3 };
      Integer[] C = A;
      System.out.println("A.equals(B) is " + (A.equals(B)));
      System.out.println("Arrays.deepEquals(A, B) is "
   + (Arrays.deepEquals(A, B)));
      System.out.println("A == B is " + (A == B));
      System.out.println("A == C is " + (A == C));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
A.equals(B) is false
Arrays.deepEquals(a, b) is true
A == B is false
A == C is true
```

Answer (score 1):

only the third one would be true.

take the first

```
int[] A = {1,2,3};
```

witch means A has position 0:1, position 1:2, position 2:3.

then take the second

```
int[] B = {1,2,3};
```

witch means B has position 0:1, position 1:2, position 2:3.

so they have the same values in each position but they are two different int arrays

but then take the third

```
int[] C = A;
```

their you are saying `int[] C is equal to int[] A,

just like saying

```
String a = "LOL";
String b = a;
```

Also just a few notes, Only strings are compared by using `.equals`anything else is compared using `==`, and always use lower case letters for variables, it makes it easier to code.

you can always test methods with this

```
if(A.equals(B)
{
    System.out.println("A.equals(B) is true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("A.equals(B) is false";
}
```

same for

```
if(A == B)
{
    System.out.println("A == B is true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("A == B is false");
}
```

Hope this helps, Luke.