# confusion about Map.containsValue method

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a following program where I have a hashmap. The keys of the hashmap are simple integers and the values are integer arrays. The program is as follows:

```
Map<String , int []> myMap = new HashMap<String , int []>();

 myMap.put("EvenNumbers", new int[]{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20});
 myMap.put("OddNumbers", new int[]{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19});
 myMap.put("DivisibleByThree", new int[]{3,6,9,12,15,18});
 myMap.put("DivisibleByFive", new int[]{5,10,15,20});

 int[] array = new int[]{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};

 System.out.println(myMap.containsKey("EvenNumbers"));
 System.out.println(myMap.containsKey("OddNumbers"));

 //The following two lines produce a false output. Why ?         
 System.out.println(myMap.containsValue(new int[]{5,20,15,20} ));
 System.out.println(myMap.containsValue(array));
```

while the following code produces a true value

```
 HashMap newmap = new HashMap();

      // populate hash map
      newmap.put(1, "tutorials");
      newmap.put(2, "point");
      newmap.put(3, "is best"); 

      // check existence of value 'point'
      System.out.println("Check if value 'point' exists: " + 
      newmap.containsValue("point"));
```

Why is this so ? Where have I gone wrong? what is the caoncept that I am missing? I feel that I am doing the same thing in both the cases. I am new to the java environment , hence the confusion. Please help me clear the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because `boolean x = new int[]{ 5, 20, 15, 20 }.equals(new int[] { 5, 20, 15, 20 });` returns false. One solution is to use java.nio.IntWrapper, try this

```
    map.put("a1", IntBuffer.wrap(new int[]{ 5, 20, 15, 20 }));
    boolean equals = map.containsValue(IntBuffer.wrap(new int[]{ 5, 20, 15, 20 }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Map uses equals to determine, if a value is present in a Map, but it means different things:

- When you compare 2 arrays in the first case, you are checking, if this is the same array meaning location in memory, not the content of an array.
- In the second case, String.equals actually checks if this is the same String.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Map.containsValue()` is looking for a match based on the `.equals()` method of the value type. The `.equals()` method of an `int[]` is effectively checking that the two references are the same.

You can check this for yourself by putting your `array` variable in the map and then asking the map if it contains your `array` variable. It should return true since it does contain an `int[]` with the same reference.

The reason it works for "point" is because `"point".equals("point")` returns true.

Comment: Use IntBuffer or your own custom class to wrap the `int[]` and make sure that .equals() will return true if the two arrays contain the same values in the same order.