# Is there difference between arr.equals(anotherArr) and arr == anotherArr?

Tags: java, arrays, equals, equality

Any array in java is `Object`. hence it has `equals` method. But I cannot watch realization of this method(or maybe is it possible ?)

I wrote several examples and always  `==` and `equals`  returns similar results.

Is there way when  `==` and `equals`  return different results ?

Comment: @Rogue Incorrect. All arrays are subclasses of `Object`.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood The only problem is that the source for arrays probably isn't in Java...

Comment: Lookie here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Comment: As others have pointed out correctly, equals and == both compare references. if you want to compare values in 2 arrays, use Arrays.equals()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is difference

1)

```
int[] a1 = {};
long[] a2 = {};
boolean r1 = a1.equals(a2);  // returns false
boolean r2 = a1 == a2;       // compile time error
```

2)

```
int[] a1 = null;
int[] a2 = {};
boolean r1 = a1.equals(a2);  // throws NPE
boolean r2 = a1 == a2;       // returns false
```

Comment: can you provide link where I can show in what cases I can use == operator without compilation errors ?

Comment: it happens when right operand cannot be cast to left operand,eg Object[] and String[] - OK. But Integer[] and String[] - error. Primitive arrays should always be same type

Comment: It is not absolutely right. jls says: **The equality operators may be used to compare two operands that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, or two operands of type boolean or Boolean, or two operands that are each of either reference type or the null type. All other cases result in a compile-time error.**
 it is not full clear for me but it is obviously differs with your answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so this is the `equals`method :

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

And it internally uses `==` operator for comparison.

You can view the javaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just write this testin a test class

```
@Test
public void testArray() {
     int[] A = {1,2};
     int[] B = {1,2};
     assertTrue(Arrays.equals(A, B));
     assertTrue(A.equals(B));
     assertTrue(A == B);
}
```

In general "==" compares the addresses while .equals() will compare using the object equals which depends on the objects (comparing to File object is different than comparing to Integers).

EDIT:

My bad, this is actually wrong,
== and equals are actually the same in java as seen there:
[equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

In case of arrays, it is indeed the same, and quite confusing I must say.
I modified my test to show the difference.

Comment: false  false in result

Comment: Writing one particular case doesn't prove a thing.  This is like trying to prove that every man in the world has the same surname, by considering Isiah Washington and George Washington.