# Neo4j - Cypher / strange output when dealing with an array as node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Using Cypher (Neo4j 2.1.2), it seems that array properties do not work well with aggregate functions.

For instance, I can have a `RETURN` clause like this:

```
RETURN meeting.title, count(participant) as number_part
```

Output: `MyTitle   2`

It well returns all the meetings's titles grouped by participants.

However, with an array as property rather than simple one like `title`, the output is strange:

```
 RETURN meeting.arrayProperty, count(participant) as number_part
```

Output:

```
MyTitle [1,2,3]  1 
MyTitle [1,2,3]  1  //not grouped by ...
```

Better than text, here's a [graphgist](http://gist.neo4j.org/?fc9672035185189521cf) I made to explain the issue, the workaround I found and what I really expect.

Does anyone know the reason? (maybe obvious...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried the following workaround: rebuild the array property as an collection:

```
RETURN extract(x in meeting.arrayProperty | x), count(participant) as number_part
```

Theory: the array property is handled as java native array whereas `extract` returns a collection (in Java sense). Comparing collections works based on comparing the elements whereas comparing a native array compares memory addresses which are different.

Comment: I don't think I figure out what doe mean your conclusion. May you explain further?

Comment: Why would a same array property be seen as several distinct memory adresses?

Comment: I guess under the hoods the `equals` method is used. However `Arrays.equals` should be used see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java. If you want to, file a github issue on https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j for this.

Comment: Ok, understood :) I'm using the workaround for the time being.

Comment: It's a bug in Cypher which has to be fixed, thanks for bringing it to attention

Comment: @MichaelHunger Ok :) No problem :) Should I have to create the ticket in Neo4j github (issue) or it's already taken into account?