# contains method for list of array of bytes

Tags: java, list, arrays, contains

so i have a list `List<byte[]>` lets say "fullList", whereby some other piece of code generates another List containing some `byte[]` partialList.  so i use the .contain method which always fails for searching got byte[] in partialList from the fullList. Why is this??

```
List<byte[]> fullList = {some byte[] arrays added here..}
List<byte[]> partialList = {some byte[] arrays added here..}

byte[] toCheck = partialList.get(0);
System.out.println("The check is "+ fullList.contains(tocheck));
```

Comment: Because it isn't in the list?

Comment: i know the byte[] should be in the list. i am generating them both.

Comment: You generate the two lists using different pieces of code.  Then pull out on element and ask if it is in a *third* list (`leafs`).  And provide *no* information as to what is in *any* of these lists.

Comment: sorry, renamed it. the lists contain hashes of some xml document parsed using jaxb.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Java arrays don't implement `equals` properly, thus two `byte[]` will only be considered equal if they are the exact same object reference. If those are hashed, try encoding those `byte[]` as `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: so how could i achieve this kind of equality check for byte[]. is searching the whole list everytime my only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Java arrays [do not implement `equals` properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279/1639625), i.e. two arrays are considered "equal" only if their memory address is the same, i.e. if they are the exact same object reference.

```
byte[] foo = {1,2,3};
byte[] bar = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(foo.equals(bar)); // prints 'false'
```

To work around this problem, you could either encode those `byte[]` as numbers and use `List<Integer>` (or `Long`) instead, or implement your own contains method using [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte[],%20byte[]%29)

```
boolean contains(List<byte[]> arrays, byte[] other) {
    for (byte[] b : arrays)
        if (Arrays.equals(b, other)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So after for every sha-256 hash i get (which i populate the list with) i encode it to some numbers. Ok thanks..