# Array.equals(...) is giving incorrect result

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

***Code That is not working***

This code is should print the word 'inside if' but doesn't and I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
doublesArray[0] = 3;
doublesArray[1] = 3;
doublesArray[2] = 3;
doublesArray[3] = 0;

int[] temp6 = {3,3,3,0};
//length is 4 for both arrays

if(doublesArray.equals(temp6))
  System.out.println("Inside if");
```

***These are things to show it should print true***

```
      int[] temp6 = {3,3,3,0};
      doublesArray[0] = 3;      
      doublesArray[1] = 3;      
      doublesArray[2] = 3;      
      doublesArray[3] = 0;
      //length is 4 for both arrays

      System.out.println("temp6 " + temp6[0] + " " + temp6[1] + " " + temp6[2] + " " + temp6[3]);
      System.out.println("doublesArray " + doublesArray[0] + " " + doublesArray[1] + " " + 
        doublesArray[2] + " " + doublesArray[3]);
      System.out.println("This should be true: ");
      System.out.println("doublesArray.equals(temp6) = " + doublesArray.equals(temp6) + "\n");

      //testing
      if(doublesArray[0] == temp6[0])
      System.out.println("correct");
      if(doublesArray[1] == temp6[1])
      System.out.println("correct");
      if(doublesArray[2] == temp6[2])
      System.out.println("correct");
      if(doublesArray[3] == temp6[3])
      System.out.println("correct");

      //testing with numbers
      System.out.println(" ");
      if(doublesArray[0] == 3)
         System.out.println("CORRECT");
      if(doublesArray[1] == 3)
         System.out.println("CORRECT");
      if(doublesArray[2] == 3)
         System.out.println("CORRECT");
      if(doublesArray[3] == 0)
         System.out.println("CORRECT");
```

These are the results I got which should show that doublesArray.equals(temp6) = true

```
temp6 3 3 3 0
doublesArray 3 3 3 0
This should be true: 
doublesArray.equals(temp6) = false

correct
correct
correct
correct

CORRECT
CORRECT
CORRECT
CORRECT
```

Thank you for those that were able to help.

Comment: the length of doublesArray is 4

Comment: You're using the `equals()` method of `doublesArray`, not `Arrays.equals(...)`.

Comment: So Arrays.equals(temp6, doublesArray)?

Comment: Yes, assuming the arrays have the same type.

Comment: Please avoid writing "solved" into the title.

Comment: Frightfully confusing how you've got an `int[]` called `doublesArray`.  I was all ready to tell you that the problem was that you were comparing `int`s to `double`s.

Comment: numbers are stored in doublesArray is the number is greater than 2 makes sense in the whole picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**doublesArray.equals(temp6) is the same as array1 == array2,** i.e. is it the same array.

**Arrays.equals(array1, array2) compares the contents of the arrays.**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] doublesArray = new int[4];
        doublesArray[0] = 3;
        doublesArray[1] = 3;
        doublesArray[2] = 3;
        doublesArray[3] = 0;

        int[] temp6 = { 3, 3, 3, 0 };
        // length is 4 for both arrays

        if (Arrays.equals(temp6, doublesArray)) {
            System.out.println("Inside if");
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Inside if
```

Comment: `doublesArray` sounds more like `double[]` instead of `int[]`. So does your solution also work if both arrays have different types?

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.equals(a1, a2)
```

compares the contents of the two arrays which is what you want to use.

```
a1.equals(a2)
```

compares the reference of a1 and a2 and it is basically the same as  comparing if a1 and a2 are pointing to the same place in memory

Answer (score 0):

**Answering own question so I get less views and others will get more**
I thought doublesArray.equals(temp6) should work but doesn't

Arrays.equals(temp6, doublesArray) works.

but don't why doublesArray.equals(temp6) is not giving an error if it doesn't work.