# How to verify password using Console class?

Tags: java, console

```
package test;

import java.io.Console;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Console console=System.console();

        char[] psw=console.readPassword("Enter Password");  // Reading Password
        char[] pswd={'a'};    // Variable to compare password entered

        System.out.println(psw);

        if(psw.equals(pswd))  // Here i do not understand how to verify password correctly?
        {
            System.out.println("Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to use the Console class correctly but i am unable to do so. Kindly correct the code if you understand my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char[],%20char[]%29), which actually compares the contents of both arrays:

```
if (Arrays.equals(psw, pswd)) {}
```

Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279/1291150) for more details.