# Method contains doesn't work

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm trying to check if a row of a csv file is present in another csv file. My code is the following:

```
public void readIncassiOLG(String filename,List<String []> itemsToCheck){
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename),CSV_SEPARATOR);
    List<String []> body = reader.readAll();
    for(String[] item : itemsToCheck){
        if(body.contains(item)){
            System.out.println("Item present");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Item not present");
        }
    }
}
```

items to check (itemsToCheck) are the rows filtered from first file, I checked that there are some row in both files, but the following method print me always "Item not present".

Any suggestion about this?

Comment: print out the values, both of your array and your list, and check whether corresponding elements are there. There might be a small difference you are overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The List's contains method returns true if this list contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

In your case, it will compare 2 String arrays.
However , `array1.equals(array2)` is the same as `array1 == array2`.

This means it will check if it is the same array.
To compare the contents of the arrays you need something like:

```
Arrays.equals(array1, array2)
```

Therefore the list's contains method is not suited for your use (i.e. comparing the array contents) but rather the equals method of the java.util.Arrays or similar.

Comment: True, more detailed elaboration can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the string is trimmed & is checked with a method similar to equalsIgnoreCase(). Basically, the actual 'contents' is not being checked in these arrays - mainly for `body`. Rework this array, trim the strings, create a fresh array & then you will be able to compare it with `item` - in a single loop/pass.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do I would suggest you try the deepEquals() in java.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

From Java documentation

> ***public boolean contains(Object o)***
>   Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and
>   only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ?
>   e==null : o.equals(e)).

To keep it simple (even if it may appear not very elegant) you should change your code as follow:

```
public void readIncassiOLG(String filename, List<String []> itemsToCheck) {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename), CSV_SEPARATOR);
    List<String []> body = reader.readAll();
    for (String[] item : itemsToCheck) {
        for (String[] bodyItem : body) {
            if ( Arrays.equals(bodyItem, item) ) {
                System.out.println("Item present");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Item not present");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if you just want to print if items is present or not (thus not doing other actions) I suggest you to run this code:

```
public void readIncassiOLG(String filename, List<String []> itemsToCheck) {
    String[] answers = {"", "not "};
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename), CSV_SEPARATOR);
    List<String []> body = reader.readAll();
    for (String[] item : itemsToCheck) {
        for (String[] bodyItem : body) {
            int present = Arrays.equals(bodyItem, item) ? 0 :  1;
            System.out.println(String.format("Item %spresent", answers[present]));
        }
    }
}
```

Buon divertimento!