# JPasswordField value and string are not equal, but they appear the same

Tags: java, string, jpasswordfield

I know people have asked this question before, but they didn't use `.equals()`.  So I am going to ask again, why is that I have two strings, but when I compare them with `.equals()` I get false.  The two strings are 1234 (`passwordField2.getPassword()` and `String s = bufferedreader.readLine()`.)  I have used s.toCharArray to compare them, and same thing.  I tried printing them both out and I got
`1234
 1234`

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thank you!

Comment: Whitespace? are their lengths equal?

Comment: Looks like there is an extra space on the second one. Try comparing them after trimming... `passwordField2.getPassword().trim().equals(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());`

Comment: @Todd I tried to do that, but `.trim()` doesn't work for a `JPasswordField`

Comment: Not `String.equal()` is not equal strings. Find out why: debugger, perhaps. Also, some objects don't support `equals()` in "expected ways", [including Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java) (for which it is equivalent to using `arr1 == arr2`).

Comment: Oh, duh, yeah. that returns a `char[]`. Maybe that's why they don't match?

Comment: @user2864740 didn't help...  Also, the JPasswordField returns a char array

Comment: @Orion31 So convert it to something useful.

Comment: @Todd I used s.toCharArray(), and it still outputted `1234`, but when compared I got `false`

Comment: @Orion31 Because `arr1.equals(arr2)` is not the equality you are looking for. Neither is `arr1.equals(str1)` or `str1.equals(arr1)`. The ideal would be `str1.equals(str2)`.

Comment: @user2864740 Char Arrays don't have any functions for converting

Comment: @Orion31 See the `String` constructor overloads. Or, by keeping with character arrays (ick!) use `Arrays.equals(charArr1, charArr2)` per the linked question. Unfortunately, `Object#equals` casts a wide net .. and catches (accepts) values, even when such do not meaningfully apply.

Comment: @user2864740 @Todd Thank you guys!  Converting the char array into a string with `String.valueOf()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword()), `passwordField2.getPassword()` returns a `char[]`.

The following code should work for you:

```
boolean passwordsMatch = bufferedreader.readLine().equals(
    new String(passwordField2.getPassword())
);
```

This code works as it converts the `char[]` to a String that can then be compared to the original `String` value.

Edit: [As Alex L. states in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35330235/2081889), `JPasswordField` stores passwords as character arrays for security purposes.

As such, a better way to write this code may be:

```
boolean passwordsMatch = Arrays.equals(
    passwordField2.getPassword(), 
    bufferedreader.readLine().toCharArray()
);
```

Comment: And now you've voided the security reason for using char[] over String

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought it might be out of scope for the question if I dive deep into password best practices in Java. I'm open to any suggested edits if they improve the answer.

Comment: Security is never out of scope, neither is correct and professional practices

Comment: Thanks @TaylorHx!  I also notice that `bufferedreader.readLine().equals(String.valueOf(passwordField2.getPassword()));` works too.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the other answers with some other points, here are a few issues:

You have extra whitespace in the second password. You shouldn't trim the string, because otherwise leading and trailing whitespace will be ignored, which is bad practice.

Also, `JPasswordField`s will return a `char[]` when you call `getPassword()` (Read why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java)), and character arrays will never equal strings. The best way (in terms of security) to solve *this* issue is to store the password as a character array. Then, you can use `Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)` to check if the passwords are equal.