# Why do == and .equals both not work with byte arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Why does == not work with byte arrays in Java?

For example:

```
    byte[] a = new byte[]{1,2,3,4};
    byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2,3,4};

    a == b //false
    a.equals(b) //false
    Arrays.equals(a,b) //true
```

Comment: because `==` compares references and not content(for objects atleast, and arrays are treated as one).

Comment: See the following [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: Also see here: [equals vs Arrays.equals in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java) - The default implementation of `equals()`, which arrays don't overwrite, uses `==` as well.

Comment: @KevinEsche It doesn't answer the `a.equals(b) // false` though. When comparing arrays Java language does something counter-intuitive compared to a regular object. `.equals` does a `==` behind the scenes. [Here is some more information with a similar question regarding primitive-arrays.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The original Title of the question didn´t ask for that.

Comment: @KevinEsche I know, the question itself did though. A typical example of just reading the title and commenting, instead of reading the actual question itself. (Hence my edit to the title. Mainly OP's fault, but I suggest reading an entire question before commenting purely based on the title.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` and `byte[]` realization of `equals` uses links comparison. In this case links point to different regions in memory. If you follow to source code for `equals` realization for `byte[]`, you'll see the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
    }
```

This actually the default implementation from `Object`

`Arrays.equals(a,b)` uses comparison of the contents of arrays.

Also, see the following [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: "If you follow to source code for equals realization for byte, you'll see..." nope. At the very least, you mean `byte[]`.

Answer (score 2):

In java, array is treated like an object. So `==` will compare only the references. Also `a.equals(b)` is same as `a==b` as default implementation in Object class check the reference only.

If you really wish to compare the content, you should use `Arrays.equals(a,b)`. Though this will not work in multidimensional array.

If you do something like below, it will result true, as both will refer the same reference.

```
b = a;
System.out.println(a==b);
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as `equals` compare if they share same memory region, and `Arrays.equals` compares the content of array.

Answer (score 0):

variable a and b are in different memory locations. 
if you print the a and b it will print with different hash codes.

hence **a == b** and **a.equals(b)** gives **false**

In the java source code equals method code is as the following

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return (this == obj);
}
```

So equals is just like the == that you are testing.
If you want to get a meaning full answer using equals method you have to override it by yourself.

and the Arrays.equals method is as the following.

```
public static boolean equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.equals(b)` just use `Object.equals()`(byte[] is a Object and donot override the method equals()), see the source:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

`==` compares reference's address.(not consider special type: String,int etc.)

Arrays.equals() compares reference's address and content, see the source:

```
public static boolean equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```