# Programming logic using TestNG

Tags: java, loops, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have 2 string arrays in a class.
I have a TestNG class in which I need to compare the values of those arrays in a Test method. The idea is, I should loop my Test method for `n` number of times where `n = {size of one of the arrays}`

`@Test(invocationCount = {fixedCount})` does not work for me, since size of the array varies.

Please let me know if I have to provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

How about to check first, if the size of the two arrays are equal? If they are not equal, then the two arrays won't be equal either.

**Edit:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java) is a thread about equality checking using Java. If I remember well, `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` is the proper way for contained element checking, but I'm not a Java guy.
If you'd like to check the elements by hand, use iteration on the arrays (you can, since their size equals now).

```
bool validator(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    if (array1 == null || array2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (array1.length != array2.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        if (array1[i] != array2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer KAI. How to proceed when the size of the two arrays are equal? My requirement is, I need to compare the arrays like: `array1[0] == array2[0] \\ first assertion in Test method` and then `array1[1] == array2[1] \\ second assertion in the same Test method`

Comment: OK. Sorry for not being precise in my question. This is what I have:  `HashMap<Integer, String[]> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();`  `HashMap<Integer, String[]> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();`  I need to iterate through the HashMap like:  `for(int i=0; I<map1.size; I++)  {  for(int j=0; j<map2.size; j++)  {  //code to compare the array which I can manage}}`  Is it possible to implement this in a TestNG Test method?