# How == and equals methods Execute in Integer and Integer[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Here i wrote simple java code.

**Integer Example**

```
class Question {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer arr1 = 1;
            Integer arr2 = 1;

            System.out.println("arr1 == arr2 is " + (arr1 == arr2));//this check object reference - this returns true 
            System.out.println("arr1.equals(arr2) is " + arr1.equals(arr2));// this check value - this also return true
        }
    }
```

**Integer [ ] Example**

```
class Question {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Integer[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        System.out.println("arr1 == arr2 is " + (arr1 == arr2));// i know this check object reference - but this return false -how it happen ?
        System.out.println("arr1.equals(arr2) is " + arr1.equals(arr2));// i know this check value - but this also return false -how it happen ?
    }
}
```

For the Integer it returns both true and that is ok.
But i can not understand For Integer[ ] how it return both false.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `equals` and `==` are identical for arrays, because array types do not override `Object.equals`. And 1 is inside the range of cached `Integer` values, so `arr1` and `arr2` are the same instance in the `Integer` case.

Comment: You can refer to this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` integers actually return true on **reference equality** because of Java integer pool. It should have returned `false` in general case. The same about `arr1` and `arr2` - they return false, because they are two different objects having two different reference addresses.

Comment: System.out.println("Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2) is "+ java.util.Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)); this returns true.but why == retuns false.that is the doubt i have ?

Comment: @Shalika that's just how `==`, `equals` and `Arrays.equals` work for arrays.

Comment: can anyone describe me how the stack memory and heap memory works in both occasions ?