# Read and Write order of RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I think the order it wrote with a randomAccessFile doesn't match with the order it read. How do I correct this? Is it something to do with Big/Little Endian?

```
RandomAccessFile accessor = new RandomAccessFile (new File("passwd_file"), "rws");   
accessor.write(macbytes);
//System.out.println(macbytes);
byte[] test=new byte[(int) accessor.length()];
accessor.seek(0);
accessor.read(test);

//System.out.println(test);
if (test.equals(macbytes))System.out.println("true");
else System.out.println("false");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Your test is invalid. The `byte[]` class does not override `Object.equals()`. Try using `Arrays.equals()`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I've been checking this for hours and always thought it was something to do with the class type and never thought about it has anything to do with the equals... Sorry I guess I am not experienced..