# Multidimensional array condition in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I want to pun a condition in an multidimesional array and I'm stuck. My method should return a name in a specific format. If find a title like (Mr.,Mrs) return Title , first letter from name , and the full surname. If title is not found return full name + full surname. Eg. Ms. S. T. Mark or Smith T. Rose or Tony Mark.

```
 String[][]  names = {
        {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. ","Miss"},
        {"Smith ", "Jones "},
        {"Tony ", "Jhon "},
        {"Mark ","Rose "}
    };
 if (names[0].equals(names)&& names[1].equals(names)&&names[2].equals(names)&& names[3].equals(names)){
return names[0][0] + names[1][0].substring(0,1)+". " +  names[2][0].substring(0,1)+". "+names[3][0];}

return"";
```

Comment: What does "I want to pun a condition in an multidimesional array and I'm stuck" mean? I think you need to explain your problem better. Also, what specifically are you stuck on? All you've said is what you want your end goal to be.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: names[0].equals(names). You are comparing String[] (names[0]) to String[][] (names)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "tile not found". You have an hard-coded array, there is always a title in there?!

Comment: I would suggest you make a Person object, which has name, last name, strings, gender, married flags. that also renders the output.

Comment: @Tschallacka Your way is perfect for this scenario. Instead of multidimensional array use Person object.

Comment: @MayurBhokase I don't think so: I think the arrays contain the possible values for the title, last name, middle name and first name.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment this doesn't make sense:

```
names[0].equals(names)
```

**names[0]** is string array (String[]) containing: {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. ","Miss"}
While **names** is array of string arrays (String[][]) containing everything, so you can't compare them in such way, it will always be false.

Moreover you actually shouldn't ever use *equals* for arrays. Please check this post for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777266/7624937

Now, as suggested by @Tschallacka you should probably create Person class, e.g:

```
class Person {
    String title;
    String name;
    String surname;
}
```

and then implement functions which are of your interest. So according to your description such function would look like this:

```
public String introduceYourself() {
    if (title != null) {
        return title + " " + name.charAt(0) + " " + surname;
    } else {
         return name + " " + surname;
    }
}
```