# What is the difference between Arrays and ArrayLists equality

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I am reading Oracle Java Certification book. I'm finding following sentences hard to grasp.

> Two arrays with the same content are not equal but ArrayLists equal.
>
> And If you call remove(0) using an empty ArrayList object, it will
>   compile successfully :/

What does it mean ? Wonder why and how ? Can anyone explain it ?

Comment: Define *equal* - are you referring to invoking the `equals` method? Why should it not compile??

Comment: I am reading OCA Java 8 book . These sentences written in there. But it is a little bit confusing..  Yeah refering invoking method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. because `equals` on arrays test for reference equality, wether or not the two variables are actually references to the *same* object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777279/2442804 `ArrayList` implements it differently and checks its contents
2. Why should it not? It is just *some* method call one *some* object that is not allowed at runtime. But that is nothing the compiler is supposed to check - period. The call compiles fine, but at runtime the code detects that you are not allowed to call that method in the given situation.