# java Set<int[]> vs Set<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

I have following code to use `int[]` and `List<Integer>` as hashset element, however, they have different result. Why `List<Integer>` could be used to compare hash, but array not?

```
Set<List<Integer>> set2 = new HashSet();
set2.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
System.out.println(set2.contains(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)));


int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Set<int[]> set3 = new HashSet();
set3.add(arr1);
System.out.println(set3.contains(arr2));
```

The output is

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple: because array equals does not compare contents. If you want to do that, you have to use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)), which of course isn't possible when using a Set (which will automatically use `array1.equals(array2)`).

That `array1.equals()` is doing a reference comparison. In other words: when using the method on arrays, you actually do use `==` under the covers! And you have two different arrays there, so they are not equal from the array perspective.

Lists on the other hand do an element by element comparison! Therefore two different list objects but the list have equal content.