# equals method not working for two list comparison

Tags: java, selenium

here i am comparing two list and will store the result in Boolean but somehow the list is same still its storing the false.

[image: img]

```
public void verify_export_Functionality() throws IOException 
    {   
        boolean b = true;
        b = Testfactory.read_element_file(models).equals(ExcelUtils.readdata("Model Export.xlsx"));
        Assert.assertTrue(b);   
        System.out.println("Pass");
    }
```

here is my list is same also

```
[test,  test1, test, tsest]
[test, test1, test, tsest]
```

Comment: check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java)

Comment: Take a read on this -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/

Comment: In addition to the given answer: Your list is not the same, there is a space in the first list which is not in the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second element in the list are different,one has space `test1`and the other do not have `test1`,that's the reason,so you need to check other parts of your code to eliminate the duplicate space

Comment: actually a comment should be better...and there is an answer in the comment already by Paul Wellner Bou. any way, upvoted ~

Comment: @Hearen sorry for that,but when I typing the answer,the comment has not appear