# Cannot decode some passwords?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, passwords, decode

I added a password checker for my program, I thought it works fine since I could save the password in a file (encoded) and could enter the password in the password field and it let me into the main program without problems. However, today I was testing more and I found out that some passwords do not work and I have no idea why that is the case.
I included both my methods, one does encode the password, the other one does decode it. The verify method I included is the one that reads from the password file, decodes the password and checks if the entered password equals the saved one. I couldnt find out what types of passwords do not work, its not the length, more like the characters which were used.
Thanks in advance

```
public static char[] encode(int offset, char[] charArray) {

    char[] arrEnc = new char[charArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

        int verschiebung = (charArray[i] + offset) % 128;

        arrEnc[i] = (char) (verschiebung);

    }
    return arrEnc;

}

public static char[] decode(int offset, char[] charArray) {

    char[] arrEnc = new char[charArray.length];

    int verschiebung;

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

        if (charArray[i] - offset < 0) {
            verschiebung = charArray[i] - offset + 128;

        } else {
            verschiebung = (charArray[i] - offset) % 128;

            arrEnc[i] = (char) (verschiebung);
        }
    }
    return arrEnc;

}

private void verify() {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(pws);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        char[] arr = br.readLine().toCharArray();
        char[] newArr = decode(arr.length, arr);
        String pw = new String(newArr);
        String masterPw = "Kassa";
        if (passwordField.getText().equals(pw) || 
                  passwordField.getText().equals(masterPw)) {
            setVisible(false);
            starto.setVisible(true);
            br.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any password should be able to be saved and decoded

Comment: Do you have specific examples of what does vs. does not work?

Comment: yes, i just tested it with "testtesttest" and it does not work

Comment: "allesklarman" worked

Comment: Please check:  "System.out.println(decode(0, encode(0, "testtesttest".toCharArray())));" - yields testtesttest for me.

Comment: I just tested changing the verify method, instead of reading the password in the file and decoding it, I encode the entered password and compare it with the saved password, then I printed them in the console and both were equal, however
 `if (testArr.equals(arr) || passwordField.getText().equals(masterPw)) {
    setVisible(false);
    starto.setVisible(true);

   }`
does not do anything

Comment: yes correct, what you said is the case, but apparently the if instruction doesnt set the other window to visible

Comment: I just tested `Arrays.equals(encPw, arr)` and apparently that seems to work, at least for "testtesttest"

Comment: Yep! works, so apparently the normal .equals methode does not work out for arrays, thanks for your help anyway! :D

Comment: Yup, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the code.

```
if (charArray[i] - offset < 0) {
        verschiebung = charArray[i] - offset + 128;
        ...
```

Here you forgot to put

```
arrEnc[i] = (char) (verschiebung);
```

So you should assign `verschiebung` to `arrEnc[i]` in the first condition block in the decode method.

Comment: it works fine now and that didnt cause the problem! I took the encode part from another site, didnt change the encode and decode method at all, only problem was what I discussed with the other guy above. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I didnt use the decode method before, now that I used it, it didnt work so I did what you said and it fixed it, thanks !