# finding a hash function for long integer array

Tags: java, hash, hashcode, hash-function

I am looking for a hash function for an integer array containing about 17 integers each. There are about 1000 items in the HashMap and I want the computation to be as fast as possible.

I am now kind of confused by so many hash functions to choose and I notice that most of them are designed for strings with different characters. So is there a hash function designed for strings with only numbers and quick to run?

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: you mean hashmap inside a hashmap? or a hashmap that accepts string as a key and integer as a value?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous description. Actually I just want to query an object by key in a hashmap. And the hashmap accepts an array of integer as the key.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058149/using-a-byte-array-as-hashmap-key-java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627889/java-hashmap-with-int-array?rq=1

Comment: it seems really odd that you'd want an int array as a key in a Map.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify any requirements (except speed of calculation), but take a look at [java.util.Arrays#hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28int%5B%5D%29). It should be fast, too, just iterating once over the array and combining the elements in an `int` calculation.

> Returns a hash code based on the contents of the specified array. For any two non-null int arrays a and b such that Arrays.equals(a, b), it is also the case that Arrays.hashCode(a) == Arrays.hashCode(b).
>
> The value returned by this method is the same value that would be obtained by invoking the hashCode method on a List containing a sequence of Integer instances representing the elements of a in the same order. If a is null, this method returns 0.

---

> And the hashmap accepts an array of integer as the key.

Actually, no!

You could technically use `int[]` as a key in a `HashMap` in Java (you can use any kind of `Object`), but that won't work well, as arrays don't define a useful `hashCode` method (or a useful `equals` method). So the key will use object identity. Two arrays with identical content will be considered to be different from each-other.

You could use `List<Integer>`, which does implement `hashCode` and `equals`. But keep in mind that you must not mutate the list after setting it as a key. That would break the hashtable.

Comment: Thanks~ I have looked at them and I just want to know more about the computation of the hashcode. Basically, I want as few hashcode collisions as possible. As there are less than 1000 items, I think it should generate almost no collison. And I also want the computation to be fast as it will be implemented for a lot of time. Thanks again for your effort~

Comment: The computation of the hash code is defined at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29. Quite simple, just additions and multiplication with 31.

Comment: I was wondering is it enough to use in this case? Are there any better solutions? I have seen some hash functions such as FNV hash and ELF hash. It seems that they are also good to implement.

Comment: You can run a test with a sample of your data. See if it "behaves".

Comment: Ok~ As I am not so familiar with hash function, so can you recommend some hash designed for array of integer except the one defined by multiplying 31 kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

hashmap functions can be found in 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Creating a hashmap is easy.. it goes as

```
HashMap<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
```