# Why LinkedHashSet is not taking order into consideration when it computes hashCode of the container?

Tags: java, collections

I wanted to use a `LinkedHashSet` as a key in the `Map`, but since the `hashCode()` of the `LinkedHashSet` object doesn't take the order of elements into consideration, my sets are considered as the same key in the map.

```
        Map<LinkedHashSet<String>, Integer> ballotsAsSets = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<List<String>, Integer> e : ballots.entrySet()) {
            LinkedHashSet<String> newKey = new LinkedHashSet<>(e.getKey());
            System.out.println("key = " + newKey + ", hash = " + newKey.hashCode());
            ballotsAsSets.put(newKey, e.getValue());
        }
```

```
ballots = {[A, B, C]=1, [B, A, C]=3, [A, C, B]=1}
key = [A, B, C], hash = 198
key = [B, A, C], hash = 198
key = [A, C, B], hash = 198
```

It seems counterintuitive.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to consider different order as a different key?  If so, why did you choose a set?

Comment: Fundamentally a `LinkedHashSet` is a `Set` and follow `Set` semantics. Therefore `new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of("A", "B")).equals(new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of("B", "A"))` is `true`.

Comment: Because LinkedHashSet has the following unique properties: it doesn't let duplicates in and has predictive iterations. And I wanted such an object to be also unique..

Comment: The sets are not considered equal because they have the same hash code, they have the same hash code because they are equal. Two objects are equal when their `equals` method says so, regardless of their hash code.

Comment: Ok, that last explanation makes sense to me: LinkedHashSet is still a Set and needs to behave like one, disregarding the predictable order of iteration.

Answer (score 2):

[Set::equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. **Returns true
> if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same
> size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set**
> (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the
> specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works
> properly across different implementations of the set interface.

and `hashCode` needs to be [consistent with `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410236/how-to-ensure-hashcode-is-consistent-with-equals).

It's dangerous to use mutable keys in Maps anyway, so you may as well convert it to an immutable list.

Comment: I mean [`Set::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#hashCode()) basically tells you the exact formula for the hashcode that implementations **have to** use.

Comment: Who is stopping you to extend from LinkedHashSet and then override equals and hashCode?

Comment: @IhorM. No one, but such a class violates the contract of the interfaces it implements, which is likely to lead to bugs. Who is stopping you from using a List?

Comment: I further used LinkedHasSet to check if an item is in the collection and to preserve order of insertion.

Comment: So, I have to copy data to an immutable list.

Comment: Anyways, it’s ok. I was surprised to see that hashCode() is not computed in a similar way as in a list.

Comment: @IhorM. you can implement your own collection that is neither `Set` nor `List` but has the desired properties. Internally, it may delegate to a `LinkedHashSet` (except for `equals` and `hashCode`)…

Comment: @Holger yes, I have arrived at the same conclusion, thanks for your opinion